# Wanderlust? Scales and scarves

Tags: knowledge

Happy Mondays everyone

Each circle represents a category (as yet unknown)

Each tile belongs in at least one category - but which ones where and why?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The left set contains

> The last words in titles of Harry Potter books.
>  **STONE** (Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone).
>  **SECRETS** (Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets).
>  **FIRE** (Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire).
>  **PRINCE** (Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince).

The right set contains

> Surnames of superheroes in the Justice League.
>  **KENT** (Clark Kent, Superman).
>  **PRINCE** (Diana Prince, Wonderwoman).
>  **CURRY** (Arthur Curry, Aquaman).
>  **ALLEN** (Barry Allen, The Flash).
>  **STONE** (Victor Stone, Cyborg).

The intersection contains

> **PRINCE** and **STONE**